# Bad performance (stuttering) with Windows Phone 7 Page Transitions

Tags: silverlight, performance, animation, windows-phone-7

I tried using the Toolkit for page transitions but all the animations were stuttering. In another question, I was suggested not to use the toolkit, so I've implemented all the animations by myself and triggered them manually. For example navigating to another page:

```
void list_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ListBox listBox = sender as ListBox;
    if (null == listBox) return;
    Data.Category item = listBox.SelectedItem as Data.Category;
    if (null == item) return;

    Uri uri = new Uri(App.MakeResourcePathTo(item.Page), UriKind.Relative);

    Storyboard storyboard = Application.Current.Resources["FlipForwardOut"] as Storyboard;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, LayoutRoot);
    EventHandler completedHandler = delegate { };
    completedHandler = delegate
            {
                NavigationService.Navigate(uri);

                storyboard.Stop();
                storyboard.Completed -= completedHandler;
            };
    storyboard.Completed += completedHandler;
    storyboard.Begin();

    listBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
}
```

Is the code ok?
There shouln't be anything else running parallel to that code, as I understand it. That's exactly what I wanted because then nothing would interfere with my animation and make it slow.

Here is another code snippet. This shows how I handle the back-Animations.

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    Storyboard storyboard = Application.Current.Resources["FlipBackwardOut"] as Storyboard;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(storyboard, LayoutRoot);
    EventHandler completedHandler = delegate { };
    completedHandler = delegate
    {
        storyboard.Stop();
        storyboard.Completed -= completedHandler;

        NavigationService.GoBack();
    };
    storyboard.Completed += completedHandler;
    storyboard.Begin();
}
```

Is there anything wrong with that code, which could cause the performance problems?

The animations are very simple, only linear animations:

```
<Storyboard x:Key="FlipForwardOut">
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Projection).(PlaneProjection.RotationY)">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="70"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="1"/>
        <LinearDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.4" Value="0.1"/>
    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

One thing I've recognized: When I'm navigating to a panorama page, the panorama page's animations are running parallel to my page-transition animations. The parorama page's baked-in animations let the title slide in, and also the panorama items slide into place. So, there are some translation-animations running parallel to my page transitions (which are basically rotation and opacity).
Can I somehow prevent the panorama from playing it's own animations, or delay them until my page transition animation has completed, respectively?

There is another problem with my page transitions: When I navigate to another page and play the animation, when the animation has completed (LayoutRoot has been rotated to Y=70, and it's opacity=0) then the original layout is displayed for a few miliseconds (with LayoutRoot rotation Y=0 and opacity=1), and then it is navigating to the next page and the animation on the next page starts.
Why is this?

I hope, someone can help me.
I'm quite frustrated after having spent so many hours on this. Regardless of what I tried, the animations showed bad performance, they are stuttering in the Emulator and on the Device. 
The animations of the preinstalled apps on the phone have smooth animations. I don't understand this. :(

Comment: I'm yet thinking of using WriteableBitmap to making a screenshot of my controls and animate that. Would be additional work which I dont' want to do only to get smooth animations. However, it doesn't fix the stuttering panorama's baked-in animations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your animation code looks to be OK, though there are probably a number of scenarios that you're not handling, so you might want to take a look at Kevin Marshall's [Page Transitions Sample](http://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/10/13/wp7-page-transitions-sample/) (which I've found to perform better than the Toolkit transitions).
However, on the assumption that your animation code is fine and that you experienced similar stuttering with the toolkit transitions, are you doing anything in the constructor of your pages? It's common for view models or data to be loaded and/or processed in the constructor, which will cause a delay in the animations because this is being done on the UI thread. You should leave as much initialisation as possible until the `OnNavigatedTo` override of your page.

Comment: I've already moved all the data-loading code to the page-transition-animation's Completed-handler in the OnNavigatedTo handler, so that shouldn't interfere with my animations. I will check out that link you posted. Thanks for it.

Comment: OK, so are the performance problems apparent on all pages, or just specific ones (i.e. the Panorama page you mentioned)?

Comment: I've done some more testing. Seems like my own page transitions are not stuttering when navigating to a normal page. I've disabled the page-enter animation on the panorama page. It seems to me that the panorama baked-in animation is stuttering. And, it doesn't look as nice as the animation of the phone's Contacts app, for example. Looking worse and performing worse, cool! Behaviors of the debug build and the release build are the same. Any more ideas?

Comment: OK, so if we've narrowed it down to the Panorama page, then the next question is: what content is in your Panorama and how/when is it initialised? Unlike the Pivot control, all PanoramaItems are loaded on startup. If there are any data bindings going on, then they can cause stuttering of animation because the binding is occurring on the UI thread and you should wait until the LayoutUpdated event before setting them. You can use the same approach as I describe in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4709019/how-can-i-check-when-the-databinding-of-a-list-is-complete-wp7

Comment: There wasn't much code in the OnNavigatedTo method, and no code at all in the page's Loaded handler. However, I've now moved the code to the constructor, there I have now: `vm.DoneLoading += (s, e) => { Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delgate { list.ItemsSource = vm.Items; }); };` and `panoramaControl.InvokeOnLayoutChanged(delegate { vm.LoadData(); });`. vm.LoadData() had been in the OnNavigatedTo method before. However, only static data is loaded, so that shouldn't have an impact on performance at all. Is there anything else I could do or is it now the performance-optimal solution?

Comment: should be `InvokeOnLayoutUpdated` instead of  `InvokeOnLayoutChanged`, of course

Comment: Is performance acceptable now, or is it still noticeably slow?

Comment: Although it were only few lines of code, performance seems to be better now. Does it really make such a big difference executing that (small, not time consuming) code directly in the `OnNavigatedTo` method versus in the `LayoutUpdated` method? However, I couldn't test on the device yet. In the emulator it looks good. Sometimes it's stuttering slightly. It is still not running as smoothly as the animations of the preinstalled apps.

Comment: Unfortunately, getting 100% smooth animations 100% of the time is something that can be unachievable in 3rd party applications. Definitely worth testing on the device, especially if you have a very powerful PC, although I've found that page animation performance is fairly comparable.

Comment: Hmm, why are the preinstalled applications 100% smooth? Aren't they silverlight apps? Are they native? Anyways, thanks a lot for helping!!

Comment: The preinstalled applications (created by Microsoft and their partners) have acccess to lower level APIs than us lowly 3rd party application developers :)

Comment: One last question: Can I be sure that `LayoutUpdated` fires after `OnNavigatedTo` always?